# How to test external redirects with cucumber?

Tags: cucumber

How can I test that I'm being redirected to an external location using Cucumber? For example after an action is executed I may want to redirect the user to an external location. Is this possible with capybara?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP redirection mechanism includes two steps:

1. **HTTP server** returns a 301 HTTP status ("Moved Permanently") with a new location (URI)
2. **HTTP agent** (capybara in your case) re-sends previous request to the new location

You are to find a way to recognize 301 HTTP response status (shouldn't be hard) using Capybara's DSL.

Also, you may want to turn Capybara's "follow_redirect" (or something similar) option off in order to prevent step #2.

Hope it helps.